# How to do I get my Web Application to access a servlet correctly?

Tags: java, html, xml

I'm try to get a simple web application up and running. I'm using the Apache Tomcat 8.5 server and my ide is Netbeans 11.1, i've imported the Java EE Web 8 API library into my project's libraries. The index.html page has 2 fields, for 2 numbers and an "Add" button that should output the sum.

[the web app index.html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6y0e.png)

However, when I click add, i get a HTTP Status 500 error.

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Error instantiating servlet class [Add]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [Add]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Root Cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Add.<init>(Add.java:1)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

I have tried removing the servlet tag from the web.xml file, it still doesn't work.

This is my index.html file;

```
<html>    
    <body>
        <form action="Add" method="get">
        Enter 1st Number : <input type="text" name="t1">
        <br>Enter 2nd Number : <input type="text" name="t2">

        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The web.xml file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Add</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Add</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Add</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Add</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

and my Add servlet;

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


@WebServlet(name="Add", urlPatterns = {"/Add"})
public class Add extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException{

        int i = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("t1"));
        int j = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("t2"));

        int k = i+j;
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println(k);
    }

}
```

[Here is also a picture of my project files;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MtsO.png)

Comment: Please don't post text as images - edit your question with the appropriate text.

Comment: Sorry, I've amended it.

Comment: you must override the get method from HttpServlet

Comment: Can you please explain how do I do that?